# Ошибка в работе с MySQL в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, .net, visual-studio

Скажите, как можно исправить ошибку в подключение к базе данных mysql. Ошибка возникает при попытки соединение через внешнее подключение, при вводе данных и начале соединении выдает ошибку: в SSL. " SSL Connection error. Сбой установки соединения из-за неожиданного формата пакета".

Код соединения с базой данных.

```
class db
   {
       MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server = ***; port=3306; username=a***ug; password=W****a; database=a**lug");
     
       public void openConnection()
       {
           if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
               connection.Open();
       }
  
       public void closeConnection()
       {
           if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
               connection.Close();
       }
       public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
       {
           return connection;
       }

   }
```

**connection.Open(); - отправляет ошибку в данном месте**

---

Есть также подключаться через плагин подключение к базе данных. Выдается ошибка - картинка.

[image: Код ошибки в программе]

Comment: По идее `MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(...` - не должно компилироваться вообще. Что за конструкторы определены в классе MySqlConnection?

Comment: если звездочку добавить, то будет компилироваться

Comment: Видимо вы C# путаете c C++